# Search in expandedRow with ant design react

Tags: reactjs, components, antd, react-component, ant-design-pro

I have a search field in the table header and need to do a search inside my expandedRow.
Today I can only find the elements that belong to the header.

Example of how is my code today:

```
getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
  <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
    <Input
      ref={node => {
        this.searchInput = node;
      }}
      placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
      value={selectedKeys[0]}
      onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
      onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
      style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
    />
    <Button
      type="primary"
      onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
      icon="search"
      size="small"
      style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
    >
      Search
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
      Limpar
    </Button>
  </div>
),
filterIcon: filtered => (
  <Icon type="search" style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />
),
onFilter: (value, record) =>
  record[dataIndex]
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
  if (visible) {
    setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
  }
},
render: text => (
  <Highlighter
    highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
    searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
    autoEscape
    textToHighlight={text.toString()}
  />
)});
```

I need it to be like this image:

[SEARCH EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTtuV.png)

Comment: Have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/n90m38q05p

Comment: I saw it, but it search is not in a expandedRow.I already looked at all the documentation of the antDesign in: https://ant.design/components/table/#header